# How do I count successive null (\0) bytes in C?

Tags: c, memory, null, libc

Is there a fast way to count the amount of successive null bytes starting from a certain (char*) pointer in C? I'm currently using a tight loop, which works well and is fast enough, but libc/gcc's string functions tend to be even faster.

I'm looking for something similar to `strspn`, buf strspn (of course) stops at the first null byte and is therefore useless for this task. I guess you could also say I'm looking for the inverse of `strlen`, which returns number of bytes that are *not* null.

Comment: If the NUL byte is not the end of the string, how do you know where the string ends?

Comment: When it's fast enough... why botter?!

Comment: There's probably some hand-written assembler in the C library implementation. You could advance up to the nearest aligned pointer and start comparing integer values.

Comment: Its only possible if youn know the length of the memory you're going to scan.

Comment: +1 for @Anthales - sure sounds like premature optimization to me!

Comment: I know the size of my buffer, so that shouldn't be a problem.  Also, believe it or not, hand-written loops like these are actually the bottleneck here... I loop over a lot of memory, many times. I count a lot of nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pointer is word-aligned, you could check it for zeroness a word at a time.

```
int zeros(char *p)
{
  int n = 0;
  if ((int)p & 1) {
    if (*p)
      return 0;
    p++;
    n++;
  }
  if ((int)p & 2) {
    if (*(short *)p)
      goto label1;
    p += 2;
    n += 2;
  }
  if ((int)p & 4) {
    if (*(long *)p)
      goto label2;
    p += 4;
    n += 4;
  }
  while (!*(long long *)p) {
    p += 8;
    n += 8;
  }
  if (!*(long *)p) {
    p += 4;
    n += 4;
  }
label2:
  if (!*(short *)p) {
    p += 2;
    n += 2;
  }
label1:
  if (!*p)
    n++;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I am uneasy about the assumption that an int is 4 chars long, etc.

Comment: `int` isn't guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer value. Use `(u)intptr_t` from `stdint.h` or, if unavailable, `size_t`.

Comment: @KyleJones: you can use `sizeof()` to check the type size. You can also use [compile-time "assert"](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Compile-Time_Asserts.shtml) to ensure your code wouldn't compile on platforms where the size is different.

Comment: @Alex I only care about the bottom few bits of the pointer value, but yes, maybe I should have used one of the other types instead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if such method exists, but if you have to write it yourself, you might consider checking sets of 4 or 8 bytes together, using a `(int*)` or a `(long*)`.

Comment: that is a good idea but in the end you have to measure. And very often the simplest solution discovers to be the faster. (I remember I was surpriced that java jit compiler tries to do 8 iteration in series to save increments, with the result that jit makes the loop slower :-( )

Comment: There is not a strong correlation between the complexity of a code and its efficiency. Size and complexity are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
char* start = ...
char* act = start;
while (*act++ == 0);
ptrdiff_t nulls = (act - start) - 1;
```

However, something should guarantee the **while** to stop before it reaches unavailable memory

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t` but not `int`.

Comment: This is essentially the tight loop I'm currently using. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a faster way to do this in portable, standard C.

The C compiler builtins and standard library can go faster, because they don't have to be written in portable, standard C - they're free to take advantage of implementation-specific knowledge.

You could of course go this route yourself - but if what you have is already fast enough, then is it really worth the portability and maintainability costs?